# Open new fragment from fragment with switch case

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am going test move to new fragment layout(2) from current fragment(1) with RecyclerView switch case intent.
But it doesnot work and keep stay in current fragment.

FragmentAdapter.java

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            tvTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            tvDesc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDesc);
            tvImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvImage);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Intent intent;
                    switch (getAdapterPosition()) {

                        case 0:
                            intent = new Intent(context, FragmentTwo.class);
                            break;

                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(context, FragmentThree.class);
                            break;

                        default:
                            intent = new Intent(context, FragmentHome.class);
                            break;
                    }
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
```

any ideas? Thankyou

Comment: What does the log say?

Comment: Have a look for managing fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing

Comment: We actually don't need the log, he's trying to start Fragments as activities. I suggest you actually inform how to use fragments, start with the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing)

Comment: Can you guys help me with a code ?

Comment: Based on his existing code, I'm guessing he's already looked at the documentation and that pointing him there again won't help too much. Moreover, if the app crashes I think it's worth checking the log to see what direction it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Declare and initialize Context in ViewHolder

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    final Context context = itemView.getContext();
```

Add the following method if Activity of fragment that loads the recyclerview extends Activity

```
private void loadFragment(Context context, Fragment fragment) {
    ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager()
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
                 .addToBackStack(fragment.getTag())
                 .commit();
```

Add the following method if Activity of fragment that loads the recyclerview extends AppCompatActivity

```
private void loadFragment(Context context, Fragment fragment) {
    ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager()
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment)
                 .addToBackStack(fragment.getTag())
                 .commit();
```

Loading the fragment of your choice in the switch case

```
switch(getAdapterPosition()) {
     case 0:
          loadFragment(context, new YourFragment());
        break;
     case 1:
          loadFragment(context, new YourFragment());
        break;
     case 2:
          loadFragment(context, new YourFragment());
        break;
     default:
          loadFragment(context, new YourFragment());
        break;
}
```

Comment: Variable 'intent' might not have been initialized, after switch case